# Where can I find the DHT in my system?

Tags: node-discovery, peers

Information about peers is stored in a Kademlia-like Distributed Hash Table in my node. Where is it stored? I know that `admin.peers` command gives me a list of nodes but I want to see the actual structure of the table with all the information about peers. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

These are stored in the the `~/.ethereum/nodes/` directory as a LevelDB database (in `.ldb` files). The reading and writing of these files is handeled by [`database.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fed692f67e81bd3937a5efab38f56a9b99d04d41/p2p/discover/database.go).

To read them you'd need a tool which understood the schema on which the database is based, which is described [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fed692f67e81bd3937a5efab38f56a9b99d04d41/p2p/discover/database.go#L56). I don't know of any existing tool for the node data, but block explorers work in an equivalent way by reading and parsing the chaindata `.ldb` files (I believe).